# Do I typehint everything in PHP?

Tags: php

Should I type hint everything (parameters and return values) whenever possible? And maybe even strive to write code that can be type hinted? In the real world with real developers which may or may not be less than stellar is there any drawback to type hinting whenever possible?

In my mind, code that breaks fast and furious is one that breaks before it can enter production most of the time.

Comment: The short answer is "Yes, please!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type hinting is the way to go. I would start with type hinting arguments (combined with interfaces), return values, and whenever you initialize a variable or property. Combined with doc blocks, and you have just documented your code in a way that allows others to pickup quickly.

```
function getValue(\Settings\Bar $foo) : string
{

    $val = (string) $foo->value;
    //..

    return $val;
}
$myVal = (string) getValue($bar);
```

If anyone makes a mistake, the debugger will pinpoint you the exact location. Moreover use

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

at the top of all your php pages to enforce type hinting and you are on your way to write enterprise level code using PHP.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. Though, isn't `$myVal = (string) getValue($bar);` this part redundant, since the function cannot return anything other than a string without throwing a fatal error in the first place? Is there a reason to type hint that particular part?

Comment: You are welcome. Good question. If there is no code in between the function/method, yes but try to make it a nasty habit and you will probably have the execution part on a different page than the function or class. Also, readability is important to your fellow coders.

Comment: `$val = (string) $something;` is not type hinting but type casting(changing type). Which might actually be a risk to use because it will force a value to be allowed even if the value should be incorrect. If you type hint return and input vars you should not need it often and if you do, you can also use an if statement with something like `is_numeric` and an else that throws an `Exception`

Comment: Sorry, just downvoted because some part of your answer is either wrong or incomplete. There is no type hinting/interfacing for variables and properties in PHP(maybe future versions). Only docblocks can help there but it won't give runtime errors. Also, note that definitely not every class in your project needs an interface. But that's another topic which can be found plenty about on SO.

Comment: The variable type hinting is all about readability and stating what that variable will contain and allowing others to read your code easier. I do agree it is type casting, if the return value is not what is expected.

Comment: @René

type hinting is available since PHP 7.4 which was introduced Nov. 28th 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Type hinting helps other developers or even you to understand the code better without deep diving into it. You don't have to understand internal logic of a class or a function, or search a manual or the Internet to know the type of a value that this or that function returns.

It also helps to prevent one from making silly errors. For example, one thinks that a function accepts an `ArrayAccess` object, but in reality, the function accepts just arrays which might cause an error.

The only drawback I can see is that it's hard to maintain type hinting and keep everything consistent due to nature of PHP itself.

So, it's heavily recommended to do type hinting whenever it's possible. With modern IDEs like PHPStorm it becomes pretty easy to maintain type hinting and keep it up to date and consistent.

Comment: I believe the OP is referring to type hints as part of the function signature rather than phpdoc type annotations, which don't suffer from the maintenance issues you describe because invalid arguments or return values will throw a TypeError.